# Progress Bar with Thread (Java Swing)

Tags: java, swing, thread-sleep

Here is a little a example:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        int x = 0;
        while (jProgressBar1.getValue() < 100) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
                x++;
                jProgressBar1.setValue(x);
                jProgressBar1.repaint();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MainWindow.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            System.out.println(jProgressBar1.getValue());
        }
    }
```

`System.out.println(jProgressBar1.getValue());` returns digits to IDE output, but jProgressBar1 doesn't draw this value. What's wrong with this code? Please help.

Comment: try looking into using `SwingWorker`

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html

Comment: I've provided an example, how it should be implemented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never use Thread.sleep() in Swing thread. Use javax.swing.Timer instead.

Example:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    final Timer t = new Timer(50, new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            jProgressBar1.setValue(jProgressBar1.getValue() + 1);
            if (jProgressBar1.getValue() == 100) {
              ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
            }
        }
    });
    t.start();
}
```

Comment: Yes it works, but it fills progressbar very-very fast. How can i change a dalay?

Comment: @alexkowalski It's the first parameter for the constructor of the Timer. Change the second line to: 
final Timer t = new Timer(250, new ActionListener() {

Comment: it doesn't help! Not 1000 not 10 000... Nothing happens, just fills very fast and that's all.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you're calling `.repaint()` in the same thread you're doing your "work" (Thread.sleep). ["repaint() does not invoke paint() directly. It schedules a call to an intermediate method, update(). Finally, update() calls paint()..."](http://www.scs.ryerson.ca/~mes/courses/cps530/programs/threads/Repaint/index.html). This means you're scheduling a bunch of `repaint()` calls, but they aren't being processed. I would also bet that once the value does reach 100 the progress bar jumps to being full, which is because the main thread has ended and all of the `repaint()` calls are finally being processed.

In order to make jProgressBars work, you have to have their repainting occur in a different thread than the one in which you are doing work (which notably should also be in a different thread - This is also true for most Swing updating). Try starting this Runnable in a new thread before you invoke your code:

```
public class ProgressBarPainter implements Runnable{
    public JProgressBar jProgressBar1;
    public void run(){
        while(true){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
                jProgressBar1.repaint();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
               break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Example **functioning** code to use the above:

```
public class Frame extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JProgressBar bar;

    public Frame(){
        JPanel contentPanel = (JPanel) getContentPane();

        JButton b = new JButton("Do Process");
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                ProgressBarPainter p = new ProgressBarPainter();
                p.jProgressBar1 = bar; //Fill in with the bar you want painted
                Thread t = new Thread(p);
                t.start();

                Worker w = new Worker();
                w.jProgressBar1 = bar;
                Thread t2 = new Thread(w);
                t2.start();
            }

        });
        contentPanel.add(b, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        bar = new JProgressBar();
        contentPanel.add(bar, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Frame();
    }

}

class Worker implements Runnable{
    public JProgressBar jProgressBar1;
    public void run(){
        int x = 0;
        while(jProgressBar1.getValue() != jProgressBar1.getMaximum()){
            try {
                //Do some work
                Thread.sleep(50);
                //Update bar
                jProgressBar1.setValue(x++);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
               break;
            }
        }
    }
}

class ProgressBarPainter implements Runnable{
    public JProgressBar jProgressBar1;
    public void run(){
        while(true){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
                jProgressBar1.repaint();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
               break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work without it anyway...
I think there is a problem with thread. I have tested it with another code: 

`int values[] = {1,5,9,20,22,25,45,50,55,70,80,90,99,100};`
       for (int value : values) {
           try {
               Thread.sleep(50);
          } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
               Logger.getLogger(MainWindow.class.getName())....
           }`
       jProgressBar1.setValue(value);
       
      }
   }

Comment: Do **not** use `Thread.sleep()` as it will freeze your Swing application.

Instead you should use a `javax.swing.Timer`.